# How to redirect domain.com to www.domain.com with Nginx?

Tags: nginx, redirect, server, drupal-8, ubuntu-18.04

I want to redirect domain.com to www.domain.com on my Nginx server. But me configuration does not work and displays the error message in the internet browser :

> The page is not redirected correctly

I added this line to do the redirection :

```
return 301 $scheme://www.domaine.com$request_uri;
```

How to correct this error ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best way is to create addition server block which will redirect your non-www domain to www one.

```
server {
    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80 ipv6only=on;
    server_name www.s1biose.com; # Remove s1biose.com here
    root /var/www/www-s1biose-com/web;
    ...
}

# Change your second block to this

server {
    server_name s1biose.com;
    return 301 $scheme://www.s1biose.com$request_uri;
}
```

Comment: @ML19 Please remove the second block, here is the full config.
https://pastebin.com/p9k5tJry

Comment: @H Dox Thanks, it works but there is no more redirection to https